# difference between CallBack and FallBack in programming

Tags: javascript

I'm a junior frontend developer. I'm trying to get used to reading documents instead of just watching video courses on Youtube or etc.

I see two words in docs that are used and I couldn't find their difference yet! would you please help me **with difference between CallBack and FallBack in programming?**

I tried to find their meaning in dictionaries and other websites but they weren't clear enough

Comment: They aren't remotely similar. Comparing them doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is like asking the difference between "location" and "vocation". It is not because words differ in only the first letter, that their meanings have anything much in common.

Comment: I just wanted to know that, when someone says "Callback" means what kind of functions and when says "Fallback" means what kind of it?

Comment: @erff-on — *any* kind of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A callback is a function that gets attached to a computation or to a network-call and should be called upon completion. It's often used with concurrency.

A fallback is code that gets executed when other code fails for some reason, e.g. when a validation fails or a database can't be reached. It's used to still do something useful in case of a failure.

You can have a callback that contains a fallback or you can have a fallback that calls a callback.

Comment: "A callback is a function that gets attached to a computation or to a network-call and should be called upon completion" — Not always true. Consider the callback function passed to `Array.prototype.sort` or `setInterval`.